# Missing right parenthesis after (or before) default 0, Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I am trying to create a table with oracle SQL two columns of the table should have default value and should not be NULL.

I am getting the error you can see below, but i am not able to understand it because the are no parenthesis to be closed there !!!!

```
CREATE TABLE ENCUENTROS (
  2  elocal constraint clave_extrana_equipos references equipos(code) not null enable,
  3  evisitante constraint clave_extrana_equipos references equipos(code) not null enable,
  4  fecha date,
  5  plocal number constraint plocal_mayor_cero check (plocal > 0) default 0 not null enable,
  6  pvisitante number constraint pvisitante_mayor_cero check (pvisitante > 0) default 0 not null enable);
plocal number constraint plocal_mayor_cero check (plocal > 0) default 0 not null enable,
                                                              *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Error solved:

[image]

Comment: Don't know if this the error, but your check constraint plocal > 0 contradicts to your default value 0.

Comment: A quick squint at [the online Oracle documentation (link)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#CEGEDHJE) shows that `inline constraint` clause comes **at the end** of the column definition, after `default` and `not null` declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
create table encuentros (
  elocal number not null 
    constraint clave_extrana_equipos_1 references equipos(code) enable,
  evisitante number not null 
    constraint clave_extrana_equipos_2 references equipos(code) enable,
  fecha date,
  plocal number default 0 not null 
    constraint plocal_mayor_cero check (plocal >= 0)  enable,
  pvisitante number default 0 not null 
    constraint pvisitante_mayor_cero check (pvisitante >= 0) enable);
```

There were several issues:

- name `clave_extrana_equipos` for constraints was used twice. Use two different names,
- columns `elocal` and `evisitante` had no type specified,
- write `default 0 not null` after type specification, before constraint.

Edit:

As @APC noticed type specification for first two columns is not needed here.

Comment: *"columns `elocal` and `evisitante` had no type specified,"*  That is legal when the column has a foreign key: the column inherits the datatype of the referenced primary key. In fact it's not just legal it's safer.

Comment: @APC I was able to create the table without specifiying the types for the columns.
questions updated.